# image are save in folder but not saved in database in yii 2.0

Tags: image, file-upload, upload, yii2, image-upload

i want to upload image to database but the image just stored in folder and not saved in database. i dont understand what is the problem, please help me, im new in yii2. the code is in actionUpdate on contoller

The _form.php :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\file\FileInput;
use backend\assets\DashboardAsset;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\User */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
DashboardAsset::register($this);
?>

<div class="user-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
    <div class='box box-widget'>
      <div class='box-header with-border'>
        <h1><?= $this->title;?></h1>
      </div>
      <div class='box-body'>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-7'>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-sm-3 label-div'>
                First Name
              </div>
              <div class='col-sm-9'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-sm-10'>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-7'>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-sm-3 label-div'>
                Last Name
              </div>
              <div class='col-sm-9'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-sm-10'>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-7'>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-sm-3 label-div'>
                Avatar
              </div>
              <div class='col-sm-9'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-sm-10'>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->FileInput() ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class='box-footer'>
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

The Controller.php :

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use backend\models\UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * UserController implements the CRUD actions for User model.
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all User models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new UserSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single User model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new User model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing User model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $path = "uploads/img/user/";
            $imageName = $model->username;
            //upload file
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            $model->file->saveAs($path.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
$model->avatar = $path.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);

$model->save()

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing User model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the User model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return User the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $avatar
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
     public $file;
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'auth_key', 'password_hash', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['username','file', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['username'], 'unique'],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            [['file'],'file'],
            [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'password_hash' => 'Password Hash',
            'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'avatar' => 'Avatar',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
            'file' => 'Avatar',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Bring me your action update or action create where you done the image uploading .Else if you need i will share my code where i have done both saving image to folder and it's path to a column in database table

Comment: @SumithChalil Sorry, There are some code that are not written, i've edited the controller, please look it back.
oh thank you.. please send me the link or email to ixcmuhammadramadhan@gmail.com

Comment: Can you also provide a code for model?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas i've added the model, please look it back

Answer (score 0):

**controller** use the same code in update action also

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use backend\models\User;

public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file');
                if ($model->file) {
                    foreach ($model->file as $file) {
                        $path = 'uploads/images/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                        $count = 0;
                        {
                            while(file_exists($path)) {
                               $path = 'uploads/images/' . $file->baseName . '_'.$count.'.' . $file->extension;
                               $count++;
                            }
                        }
                        $file->saveAs($path);
                        $files[] = $path;
                    } 
                      $model->file = implode(',', $files);
                     $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);}

         else{
         $model->file= $model->first_name;
         $model->save();
         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
         }
            }
        else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

now add the following to your user model(not mandatory)

```
[['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png,gif,jpg', 'maxFiles' => 15],
```

just try the above to your code,and inform me if any error we can make it work together

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove `avatar` from required section of model rules.

second put this line `$model->file->saveAs($path.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);`
after the 
`$model->save();`

third check all syntax is corrected, because i can see in `actionUpdate` one semicolon is missing.

now your new `actionUpdate` looks like below:

```
  public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $path = "uploads/img/user/";
            $imageName = $model->username;
            //upload file
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

$model->avatar = $path.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;

$model->save();

 $model->file->saveAs($model->avatar);

// or   $model->file->saveAs($path.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

one most important thing remove all other column that are not visible to form from required rules. else data will never save in db.

now your model rules looks like below:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[ 'first_name', 'last_name'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['username','file', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
           //[['username'], 'unique'],
          //  [['email'], 'unique'],
            [['file'],'file'],
          //  [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }
```

one more thing set default value of other fields in db as `NULL`
or add all other fields to the form so you can enter values it those also.